# Utilizar domínios diferentes dentro de um site principal (guia de cidades)

Tags: php, mysql

Queria uma luz para a seguinte situação:

Tenho um site (guia online) principal www.siteprincipal.com.br. Neste site tenho uma tabela de cidades onde cadastro cada uma e mostro o conteúdo da seguinte maneira:

ID: 1 | Cidade: Araxá | TAG: araxa | Acesso: www.siteprincipal.com.br/araxa
Ex de página interna: www.siteprincipal.com.br/araxa/contato

ID: 2 | Cidade: Uberaba | TAG: Uberaba | Acesso: www.siteprincipal.com.br/uberaba
Ex de página interna: www.siteprincipal.com.br/uberaba/contato

ID: 3 | Cidade: Ituiutaba | TAG: Ituiutaba | Acesso: www.siteprincipal.com.br/ituiutaba
Ex de página interna: www.siteprincipal.com.br/ituiutaba/contato

Porém desejo registrar e usar um domínio específico para cada cidade assim (lembrando que tudo vai estar hospedado dentro do www.siteprincipal.com.br):

www.dominioaraxa.com.br => Ex de link: www. dominioaraxa.com.br/contato
www.dominiouberaba.com.br => Ex de link: www. dominiouberaba.com.br/contato
www.dominioituiutaba.com.br => Ex de link: www.dominioituiutaba.com.br/contato

RESUMINDO: Quero hospedar o site no domínio principal (www.siteprincipal.com.br) mas que as pessoas possam acessar ele pelo domínio com nome de cada cidade (dominioaraxa, dominiouberaba, dominioituiutaba, etc...).

Alguma ideia de como fazer isto? Se estudando e mexendo no HTACCESS e/ou mexendo nos DNS de cada domínio. Alguém com experiência nisso para apontar um caminho?

Lembrando que redirecionar somente NÃO ME ATENDE, pois aí a URL vai ficar com o link do site principal, e eu queria que mostrasse em cada cidade o domínio separado.

Trabalho com hospedagem Linux e programo utilizando PHP e banco MySQL.

Obrigado.

Comment: com laravel tu faria subdominios fácil.

Comment: http://duvidas.laravel.com.br/forum/07-16-2014-route-group-com-subdominio-menos-para-www?page=1

Comment: .htaccess é o melhor caminho. Eu iria nesta opção, mas como isto seria uma opinião, vou apenas deixar um comentário.

Answer (score 2):

### Eis um caminho simplificado sem depender do `.htaccess`:

- O PHP tem a variável `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, que serve para indicar qual domínio o cliente está usando para acessar seu site.
- Para isto, configure o servidor para que a mesma pasta atenda vários domínios.
- Você deve configurar todos os DNS para apontar para o referido servidor.

Aí, no PHP pode usar várias técnicas, como buscar o domínio no DB, ou usar por exemplo um switch:

```
switch ( $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] )

{
   case 'www.cidade-um.com.br':
       $titulo = 'Cidade Um';
       $logo = '/assets/cidadeum.png'
       break;

   case 2:
       $titulo = 'Cidade Dois';
       $logo = '/assets/cidadedois.png'
       break;

   // ... e assim por diante ...
}
```

A vantagem do switch é evitar sobrecarga de acesso ao DB em toda página, e esse switch pode ser gerado via meta-programação, para acompanhar alterações no DB.

### Por outro lado...

Se você gerenciar isto pelo `.htaccess` ou mesmo pela configuração do servidor, poderia criar situações mais interessantes, usando `mod_rewrite`.

Assim, você poderia servir cada domínio por um PHP separado, como `araxa.php`, `uberaba.php`, e estes arquivos poderiam ter apenas as variáveis necessárias para configurar o ambiente dos sites, e nelas dar um `require` no script principal que serviria para todos os domínios (caso tenha partes de código diferentes em cada cidade).

> Tentei só dar um esboço de algumas das muitas possibilidades. Se for o caso, dê mais detalhes das necessidades específicas, ou trabalhe com cada problema em perguntas separadas, assim poderá ter respostas mais completas.